# Permalinks not working even after fixing .htaccess file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I just moved my wordpress site. after moving all pages other than the homepage was showing up as 404 not found. Here are the steps I have tried.

I have changed to default permalinks and it works fine with those.

adding the following code to .htaccess

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  **RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status**
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

any idea what it could be? the link is http://dev.pwlawyers.ca/

Answer (score 0):

Your server is running Nginx web server, and .htaccess is for Apache web server.

Comment: you are right, i am dumb. Any chance you can give me the basics on what to do to get this right. I dont usually deal with this. Usually just move everything with duplicator and never had a problem.

Answer (score 0):

SO i think i have fixed it :

If your wordpress installation is in root of folder then add this to config file location block :

```
location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

If it is in a folder for example wordpress folder then add that :

```
location /wordpress/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;
}
```

Reload nginx and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Add a filter**

you can add the following filter via plugin (or theme functions, etc.):

`// Stop WordPress from modifying .htaccess permalink rules`
`add_filter('flush_rewrite_rules_hard','__return_false');`

Thanks